# JSF 2 / primefaces : p:panel not rendered with ajax?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Im not sure if this behaviour is normal or not.
Im hoping that my `panel` will be rendered only after clicking on a button that triggers an `ajax` request.

Not using Ajax works fine :

1. `p:panel id="myPanel" rendered="#{myBean.flag}"`
2. `p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{myBean.setFlagToTrue}"`
3. before clicking the button, the myPanel is not displayed `(flag = false)`
4. clicking the button, will set the flag to true, and myPanel is rendered fine

Using ajax fails :

1. `p:panel id="myPanel" rendered="#{myBean.flag}"`
2. `p:commandButton ajax="true" action="#{myBean.setFlagToTrue}" update="myPanel"`
3. before clicking the button, the myPanel is not displayed `(flag = false)`
4. clicking the button, will set the flag to true (as displayed by my log file), and myPanel **is not rendered**

I've tried omitting the rendered attribute, and indeed the ajax works fine.
I can tell that by looking at the changes reflected inside the panel.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

put your panel with conditional rendering inside another and update it. Like this:

```
<p:outputPanel id="toUpdate">
  <p:panel id="myPanel" rendered="#{myBean.flag}">
  </p:panel>
<p:outputPanel>

<p:commandButton update="toUpdate"/>
```

This is a known issue. The element can't be updated if it doesn't exist in DOM.

Comment: Why do we have to this ?